Laravel 10 - The GET method is not supported for route ..... Supported methods: POST. Event the route user POST
I created a web with Laravel 10 then hosted it in a shared hosting. Recently I got the problem with error message The GET method is not supported for route poi/proses-upload-foto. Supported methods: POST.
Basically, this is just a simple image upload page.
Here the code :
web.php
Route::get('/poi/upload-foto/{id}', [PoiController::class, 'form_upload_foto']);
Route::post('/poi/proses-upload-foto', [PoiController::class, 'proses_upload_foto'])->name('image.store');

Controller
public function form_upload_foto(Poi $poi, $id){
        $qry = Poi::where('id', $id)->get();
        return view('poi.upload_foto', ['data' => $qry[0]]);
    }

    public function proses_upload_foto(Poi $poi, Request $req){
        $req->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $imageName = time() . '.' . $req->image->extension();
        $req->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

        if($req->deskripsi){
            $poi::where('id', $req->id_marker)->update(array('image' => $imageName, 'deskripsi' => $req->deskripsi));
        }else{
            $poi::where('id', $req->id_marker)->update(array('image' => $imageName));
        }

        return back()->with('success', 'You have successfully uploaded an image.')->with('image', $imageName);
    }

view

@extends('master')

@section('isi')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary col-md-8">
            <div class="panel-heading mt-5">
                <h4><strong>Upload Foto</strong></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <img class="mb-3" src="/images/{{ Session::get('image') }}" style="width: 250px;">
                @endif

                <form action="{{ route('image.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
<div class="col-md-10">
                        <label for="judul" class="form-label">Judul</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" id="judul" name="judul"
                            value="{{ $data->nama }}" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    @if ($data->deskripsi == '')
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="deskripsi" class="form-label" rows="4" cols="40">Deskripsi</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="deskripsi" name="deskripsi"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="deskripsi" class="form-label">File Foto</label>
                        <input type="file" name="image" id="inputImage">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    @error('image')
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror

                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection


<form class="row g-3">

</form>

for the route I think I write correct code. What did I miss ?
Thank you

When does it gives the error? Also why is there  after endsection?
